# Show composited layer borders(blue border)

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, hardware-acceleration

I made simple reduced test case([**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/vorozu/quiet)) to check if `filter`,`opacity` and `transform` run on **compositor thread** while animating, and they are. If you open **Chrome Dev Tools** and use a feature *Show composited layer borders* you will see that first div has **blue** border around and last 2 has **orange** border. Why is this, bug or a feature ? I am on Ubuntu, so can you guys see this behavior on other platforms too ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is here [Debugging-composited-layers](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome#TOC-Appendix-E:-Debugging-composited-layers)

And also you can see [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/cc/debug/debug_colors.cc&q=debug%20borders&sq=package:chromium&l=7) that Chromium uses different colors based on some conditions.

Code is very well commented and for example images should have `olive` color if they are composited. I tested that on [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/dixasi/quiet) and the image has olive border if you turn on *--show-compisited-layer-borders*.

Here is the code fragment and comment.

```
// Image layers are olive.
SkColor DebugColors::ImageLayerBorderColor() {
  return SkColorSetARGB(128, 128, 128, 0);
}
int DebugColors::ImageLayerBorderWidth(const LayerTreeImpl* tree_impl) {
  return Scale(2, tree_impl);
}
```